# KAA IoT Server Configuration - Spring+Hibernate Exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kaa

I am new to Spring, having an requirement for KAA Project (IoT).

Followed [KAA Installation Guide](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Installation+guide). Done all the required configuration.

Kindly help me out with the fix for this exception.

Getting following error after login as super admin.

> Unexpected service error occurred: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]

Tried both node service kaa-node.deb. Both are throwing an same error.

1. pre-built packages.
2. Built from the source code.

Attached Server Log.

```
2016-08-11 16:25:14,308 [qtp314771492-79] ERROR o.k.k.s.admin.services.util.Utils - An unexpected exception occured!
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:218) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:57) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:44) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.service.UserServiceImpl.findAllTenants(UserServiceImpl.java:135) ~[dao-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.service.UserServiceImpl.findAllTenantAdmins(UserServiceImpl.java:146) ~[dao-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.findAllTenantAdmins(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.control.service.DefaultControlService.getTenantAdmins(DefaultControlService.java:406) ~[kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.KaaAdminServiceImpl.getTenants(KaaAdminServiceImpl.java:439) ~[kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.spring4gwt.server.RPCHelper.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPCHelper.java:56) [kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.spring4gwt.server.RPCHelper.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPCHelper.java:40) [kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.java:59) [kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:485) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:290) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:606) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:535) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getJdbcConnectionAccess(AbstractSessionImpl.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.<init>(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1589) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:999) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:122) ~[spring-orm-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.impl.sql.HibernateAbstractDao.getSession(HibernateAbstractDao.java:56) ~[dao-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.impl.sql.HibernateAbstractDao.getSession(HibernateAbstractDao.java:63) ~[dao-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.impl.sql.HibernateAbstractDao.getCriteria(HibernateAbstractDao.java:72) ~[dao-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.common.dao.impl.sql.HibernateAbstractDao.find(HibernateAbstractDao.java:227) ~[dao-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
2016-08-11 16:25:14,310 [qtp314771492-79] ERROR org.spring4gwt.server.RPCHelper - Unexpected exception occured while invoking service method - getTenants
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.spring4gwt.server.RPCHelper.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPCHelper.java:56) [kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.spring4gwt.server.RPCHelper.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPCHelper.java:40) [kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.spring4gwt.server.SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.processCall(SpringGwtRemoteServiceServlet.java:59) [kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) [gwt-user-2.7.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1667) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.9.RELEASE.jar:3.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:485) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:290) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248) [jetty-server-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540) [jetty-io-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:606) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:535) [jetty-util-9.2.2.v20140723.jar:9.2.2.v20140723]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.shared.services.KaaAdminServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.util.Utils.handleException(Utils.java:66) ~[kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.util.Utils.handleException(Utils.java:40) ~[kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    at org.kaaproject.kaa.server.admin.services.KaaAdminServiceImpl.getTenants(KaaAdminServiceImpl.java:449) ~[kaa-node-0.9.0.jar:na]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that you use configuration in sql-dao.properties and admin-dao.properties corresponding to chosen MariaDB or PostgreSQL database as described in the [switching between MariaDB and PostgreSQL](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Installation+guide#Installationguide-SwitchingbetweenMariaDBandPostgreSQL) documentation section. Also default Kaa 0.9.0 deb package are built with mariadb-dao maven profile, that means that we assume that you will be using MariaDB SQL database. So in order to use PostgreSQL you need to follow next steps:

1. Connect to Kaa node over ssh and stop kaa-node service

   `$ sudo service kaa-node-stop`
2. Download and add jar file with latest PostgreSQL database driver into Kaa's classpath (**/usr/lib/kaa-node/lib**).
3. Edit **/usr/lib/kaa-node/conf/sql-dao.properties** file according to postgresql-dao.properties.template which placed in the same directory (**/usr/lib/kaa-node/conf/**)
4. Edit **/usr/lib/kaa-node/conf/admin-dao.properties** with corresponding driver_className, jdbc_url, hibernate_dialect, password and username properties from **postgresql-dao.properties.template** file.
5. Edit **/usr/lib/kaa-node/conf/nosql-dao.properties** file according to name of chosen NoSQL database (cassandra or mongodb, mongodb is set by default).
6. Start kaa-node service

   `$ sudo service kaa-node-start`

Or you can [build Kaa server from source](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Building+Kaa+server+from+source) including corresponding Maven profile postgresql-dao as described in the [available maven profiles](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Building+Kaa+server+from+source#BuildingKaaserverfromsource-Availablemavenprofiles). In this case you don`t need to download and add jar file with PostgreSQL database driver into Kaa's classpath.

If it wouldn't help, please provide more information about your installation steps.

Comment: I'm using mariaDB, tried installing both Pre-built packages as well Kaa server from source with default profile(i.e., Maria DB)